# How to change shading of selected faces with retopo - 2.79 comparison

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface, shaders

2.79 renders the underlying selected mesh more "pronounced" over the other objects when in editmode. This is a common situation when doing lowpoly retopo over highpoly. In 2.8 its really sinks in to the other mesh and its harder to see affecting retopo-workflow in a negative way sometimes. Can this be adjusted somewhere in the preferences? If not I wish it would behave more similarly to the old system. This example has a subdivided icosphere (3) as the highpoly and the lowest subdiv as lowpoly in both blenders. Its hard to explain this issues, so please see the attached picture. Cheers.
[image]

Comment: Even in 2.7 it was not easy, maybe try Properties editor > Object > Viewport Display > Front option? Also the transparency (alt Z) makes it more visible... but someone may have a better answer...

Comment: I dont even seen that option in 2.8 - I just wish there was a way to tweak this. Doing retopo sometimes is a pain now in 2.8 - with all the Ubisoft and Epic collab I would think this is a major issue when thinking about workflows for games.

Comment: what option don't you see?

Comment: Properties editor > Object > Viewport Display > Front option --- this one. Am I looking at the wrong place? Im going through Preferences

Comment: No, the Properties editor is the panel on the right by default

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah I dont think that works for me, I still want to see the highpoly too. Oh well, I hope the devs can implement something for this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is some function already there - when you zoom out the object becomes more visible on top of the other objects. This has been in all versions I remember. I guess they tweaked it for 2.8 or its a side-effect of something else that was changed.

Comment: yes some improvements are still necessary in my opinion but maybe I miss something   ;)  I'm still a bit lost with 2.8